# Vagrant fails to bring up eth1 on Xubuntu 16.04 guest

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, vagrant

I am relatively new to Linux and Vagrant. I updated my VM guest system (VirtualBox 5.0.18 + Vagrant 1.8.1 on a Windows Host) from Xubuntu 15.10 to Xubuntu 16.04 a while ago. At that point or shortly after I noticed some oddities, e.g. a misaligned mouse cursor (a few pixels off) and missing shared directories. My guess is that it's due to the following error reported during `vagrant up`:

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9000 (guest) => 9000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 5.0.18 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifup eth1

Stdout from the command:

Failed to bring up eth1.


Stderr from the command:

mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/ubuntu-fan exited with return code 1
```

I looked for the error in combination with Vagrant and VirtualBox online, but the cases I found seemed all a bit different to mine. People write about `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` - but it does not seem to exist on my machine, neither does `/etc/sysconfig`.

Trying to run `/sbin/ifup eth1` for some more information after logging in gives me this:

```
vagrant@IDE-machine ~ $ sudo /sbin/ifup -v eth1
Configuring interface eth1=eth1 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.56.21/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.56.255     dev eth1 label eth1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

My Vagrant file looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # a locally stored box
  config.vm.box = "IDE-machine"

  config.ssh.private_key_path = "ssh/id_rsa"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.21"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.gui = true

      vb.memory = "12288"
      vb.cpus = 2
      vb.name = "my_IDE-machine"

      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--monitorcount", "1"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "64"]
      vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA", "--port", 1, "--device", 0, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "V:/BoxStorage/Projects.vdi"]
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/vagrant/provision.sh"
end
```

Guest additions are installed, I use the `vagrant-vbguest` plugin which had set up the right guest addon version earlier.

Does someone have an idea what could be the issue, or hints how I can dig further?

**Update:**
I was pointed to this: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7155 (which does not apply completely to my case)
Which led me to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes/732638#732638

I tried changing `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"`, then `update-grub` as root and reboot, to no avail.

Some more poking around showed me this:

```
vagrant@IDE-machine ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 192.168.56.21
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

**Update 2:** As requested here is the output of dmesg and the contents of ubuntu-fan:

```
vagrant@IDE-machine ~ $ dmesg | grep eth
[    1.692133] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:af:31:b4
[    1.692144] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.068113] e1000 0000:00:08.0 eth1: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:94:1e:dc
[    2.068120] e1000 0000:00:08.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    5.732516] e1000: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[    5.732980] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[    5.733061] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[    6.790923] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.793512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.795646] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[    6.796069] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

```
vagrant@IDE-machine ~ $ cat /etc/network/if-up.d/ubuntu-fan 
#!/bin/sh

set -e

case "$IFACE" in
lo) exit 0 ;;
fan-*)  exit 0 ;;
esac

case "$ADDRFAM" in
inet) ;;
*) exit 0 ;;
esac

# NOTE: NetworkManager simply does not call out to the normal
#       down hooks as it only checks _after_ the interface has
#       been lost.  Roll with this.
case "$PHASE::$METHOD" in
post-up::static|post-up::dhcp|post-up::NetworkManager)          ;;
pre-down::static|pre-down::dhcp|post-down::NetworkManager)      ;;
*) exit 0 ;;
esac

case "$MODE" in
start|stop) ;;
*) exit 0 ;;
esac

/usr/sbin/fanctl net "$MODE" "$IFACE"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check your `/etc/network/interfaces` config files ? Maybe you have several gateways as pointed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304898/trying-to-configure-eth0-and-eth1-but-failed-to-bring-up-eth1) .

Anyway, tweaking that file a bit and playing with `ifconfig` can help you drag the problem out. Check the permissions also, I doubt it comes from there but still :/

You can try to go back to a simpler configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` if it's not already the case and go back bit by bit to the original configuration file. I would do that I think.

EDIT:
From your `dmesg` output it seems that links are ready so the network part should be ok.
If you make `dmesg | grep eth`, is there any relevant information ?

Also, can you cat `/etc/network/if-up.d/ubuntu-fan` ? It exited with exit code 1, could be interesting to check what's happening there.

UPDATE:

You `dmesg` output seems okay, the links eth0/1 are ready in the end so the network should be working.

You should try to execute the `ubuntu-fan` script line by line and check for exit codes (`echo $?`, should be `0`). I wonder if the problem doesn't come from the `fanctl` program at the end. It is normaly used to control fans on a machine, but here it's a VM so ... If it's coming from this line, you can try to look why it's failing, but I would remove the `fanctl` line, and then maybe the whole file in fact. I guess the other lines are here to handle events to trigger `fanctl`.

I have checked my vagrant VMs (mostly ubuntu 14.04 though) and I don't see any `fanctl` anywhere ... I  not sure it makes sense to try to control fans inside a VM.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. I just had posted the content of the `/etc/network/interfaces` config file. Seems pretty simple to me, and I'd assume that the vagrant generated lines should be exactly what vagrant needs.

Comment: Yes sorry, I answered a little bit too quiclky ... I edited the message, can you look for dmesg and ubuntu-fan ?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, really appreciate it. I appended the two outputs you requested to the original question.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, I finally got the time to have a look at it again. Removing the call to `fanctl` seems to have solved the issue. At least the VM now starts up without error messages, and the directories mapped to the host now contain the host's files as expected.